# Use of a single cell lipo for VIN enough to power motors and board

Tags: power-supply

I successfully powered two tiny brushed motors and an MCU using a single 1S Lipo (3.7V) battery 300mAH. I did this by supplying battery power directly to the motor controller and VIN in parallel. Per datasheet, the external power supply inputs voltage range for VIN should be 7-12V. The motors spun even though I am below that range, why? In this case, using just 3.7V for VIN.

This makes me believe that 3.7V can be used for the +5V input as well to run the motors. If that's the case, then I won't even need the LD1117 voltage regulator if I plan to use a 1S to power everything, correct? I would still need the LD39050 voltage regulator if I plan to add logic devices.

Questions:
Is there a more efficient, less power drain, or reliable way to share a battery between MCU and motors than in parallel as done above? I read that I may need to decouple the shared supply for noise.

Is there anything I need to be aware of when using a small 1S Lipo to power everything as a standalone unit besides less battery life?

A 5V voltage regulator is unnecessary if my power supply is not above 5V, correct?

I am trying to make something like the jumping parrot drone without the jumping, but make it smart enough that it doesn't just die because of terrible design flaws. I have plans to incorporate wifi, sensors, and battery management IC on top of the motor controller. My goal is to have it drive but only using the 1S. The brushed motors I used are taken from a quad and they have no specs on them that I know of other than 5.5mm diameter and 18mm length. I just know they use 1S Lipo.

[STM32 Nucleo-64 boards](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf) page 60/66

Comment: Was the USB port plugged in? And no, 3.7V is not sufficient to power the Arduino VIN port.

Comment: A DC brushed motor speed will be roughly proportional to voltage. It will run at reduced speed and reduced torque.

Comment: @TomCarpenter The USB port was not plugged in. Board and motors ran all by themselves off the one battery.

Comment: ATMega was probably running at 2V then. Surprised it didn't brown out. Did you measure the voltage on the 5V line of the Arduino?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Its actually a STM32F3 board that supports Arduino connections. Sorry for misleading. I believe this board can be powered alone with 3.3V, but didn't know it can be done through VIN.

Comment: Perhaps then you should show the schematic of the power input of that board not an Arduino. Because otherwise how are we supposed give useful advice when you show something potentially completely different from what you are working with.

Comment: I have plans to update the actual schematic and show the link when I'm on my home pc. In the meantime, I drew a schematic that is the actual schematic without the details.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, providing the board with 3.7V on the VIN pin will result in a massive under voltage on the supply rails due to regulator dropout.

The LD1117 used on the input has a dropout of around 1.2V which is then followed by a diode which will have around 0.5V dropout - as a result the 5V rail will end up being 2.5V or so assuming a fully charged LiPo (4.2V - 1.2 - 0.5) or closer to 2V for a nominal charge (3.7 - 1.2 - 0.5).

The 3.3V rail will then be closer to 1.8V based on the second regulator which is only around 0.2V dropout. I'm honestly surprised the MCU actually runs correctly at that voltage, though it is probably just about within spec.

---

Bypassing the 5V regulator would allow the 3.3V rail to correctly regulate as it has sufficiently low dropout voltage to do so - you need at least 3.5V in order to maintain the output voltage of that regulator. As the LiPo discharges it will get down towards 3V, by which point the 3.3V rail will have begun to drop off again. So it is still not ideal, but should be workable for a large portion of the battery charge.

To bypass you would need to connect the 3.7V to JP5 pins 2 and 3 leaving pin 1 disconnected. This should ensure power is provided to all parts of the board which need it, and also mean that if you connect the USB port it doesn't start to charge the battery incorrectly.

You will still not have a 5V rail, however all parts of the board use 3.3V rails which are regulated using ultra low dropout regulators from the 5V line which should be able to maintain regulation even with a LiPo on their input.

Comment: Yes, that is very clear how you explained it. I am aware that I will not have a 5V rail since my battery is well below that, but wouldn't I have a voltage rail for whatever my battery voltage is at just before the input of the LD39050? I'm thinking maybe use that for motors.

Comment: The 5V rail would end up being the voltage of the battery if you bypass the 5V regulator using JP5, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few concerns/comments with your approach.

1) Do you plan on putting a battery controller on this so your lipo does not go into deep discharge? This is a potential fire/safety hazard. You might be able to get a controller/regulator in a single package.

2) Non-isolated logic/motor supplies can cause logic dropouts.

3) If you need 5V from a lower power source (3.7V), a charge pump may be useful.

4) It should be reasonable to to power an LED from 3.3V, check specs of LEDs. Some need higher voltages.

5) Consider using an h-bridge or a motor controller, that way you can get at least forward/reverse control.

Comment: 1) Yes, considering a gas gauge IC 2) Haven't quite figured out how to isolate supply from research yet 3) Stole motors off an old quad which I think uses only 1S Lipo, therefore, would like to power everything from 3.7V if possible 4) LED on board lit with 3.7V, but dimmer than when I used two separate batteries for board and motors 5) I used TB6612FNG

Answer (score 0):

LiPo batteries are rated as nominally 3.6V or 3.7V but have a working voltage range of about **3.0V** to 4.2V. I the battery was above 80% charge it would have been at 4.2V on light load. Your motor may or may not meet your need at 3V.

Unless you DESIGN what you do, your approach invites sorrow and disaster, alas. A motor spinning and spinning usefully may or may not be quite different things. Only you can tell (as you've given us no data) whether the motors will meet your needs at 3V.

LiPos will discharge to below 3V if you make them do so but wise use is to stop discharge at about 3V minimum. Whether your processor will run reliably at 3V at the clock speed you intend to use depends on whether your processor will run reliably at 3V at the clock speed you intend to use. ie until YOU can state exactly what your design is nobody can tell you what the undisclosed system will do.

Changing Vbat across 3V - 4.2V range may be OK or may not. You need to tell us more.

At Vbat = 3V you do not want to waste ANY voltage drop - no series diode, no usual regulator - a super low dro out LDO of\r a controlled FET switch.

You CAN successfully parallel motors and processor and more from the same liPo cell IF you filter and design correctly. Just connecting them is likely to have predictable and undesirable results.

Tell us ALL about what you want to do and not HOW you intend to do unknown things and we can help.

Comment: UPDATED. I am taking notes, thank you @Russell. Although motors run for me at first glance, I didn't run them long enough to ask myself whether they run at the speed I want over a discharging voltage. I think I was focused on how I got the motors to even run at all doing nonsensical things otherwise known as experimenting for me and had to stop and ask before I did damage I don't know about.